# PHP function shuts down on SoapClient::__doRequest connection timeout

Tags: php, function, soap-client, fatal-error

I am attempting to write a background function that communicates with an external API to retrieve & update information on about 500,000 records on our server. This takes time to run. The problem I'm running into is this PHP fatal error from a function called inside a foreach loop, which shuts down the function entirely:

```
SoapClient::__doRequest(): connect() failed: Connection timed out in /path/to/function on line ABC
```

Here is a mock version of the function, with an indication of the line where the fatal error is being thrown, shutting down the function:

```
private function APIUpdateFunction($table,$record,$fields,$data) {

    $soap = new SoapClient("https://www.endpoint.com/API/stuff.whatever");

    $result = $soap->UpdateRecord(array(  

        "credentials"   => API_CREDS,
        "table"         => $table,
        "record"        => $record,
        "fields"        => $fields,
        "data"          => $data                                    

    )); // THIS IS WHERE THE FATAL ERROR IS BEING THROWN

}
```

What I would like to do is create a workaround where IF the function shuts down as a result of this connection timeout, I would like to either:

A) Perform a new set of actions, such as restarting the function itself

or

B) Bypass the error entirely, and check in the next step for a response value. For example, if $result = NULL, the remaining items in this function would be bypassed and return a FALSE value.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the time your script takes to connect to the remote host/service and the time for how long the socket connection should wait for a response from the server.

The first option can be configured by specifying the timeout when you create the Soap Client:

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array("connection_timeout"=>15));
```

The second option can be configured using:

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 180);
```

Now if you want to catch a timeout error, either during the host connection or the socket connection, you should catch a `SoapFault` exception, for example:

```
private function APIUpdateFunction($table,$record,$fields,$data) 
{
    try {
        $soap = new SoapClient("https://www.endpoint.com/API/stuff.whatever");

        $result = $soap->UpdateRecord(array(  

        "credentials"   => API_CREDS,
        "table"         => $table,
        "record"        => $record,
        "fields"        => $fields,
        "data"          => $data                                    

        )); // THIS IS WHERE THE FATAL ERROR IS BEING THROWN
    } catch (SoapFault $e) {
        // There was an error with the Soap Client
        // Do something here
    }
}
```